# Elasticsearch x-pack is enabled head can't connect

Tags: elastic-stack, xpack

I can connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:9200 use head-plugin without x-pack.

When my elasticsearch 5.2.0 x-pack is enabled the xx.xx.xx.xx:9200 need logon can to connect to es ,
but head 9100 can't connnect to xx.xx.xx.xx:9200, where to enter the user and password for x-pack.

I try the setting in elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.allow-headers: Authorization
```

And use the url to connect to es

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/es-head/?auth_user=elastic&auth_password=changeme
```

But it cannot work.I got this response message..

```
"missing authentication token for REST request [/es-head/?auth_user=elastic&auth_password=changeme]"
```

My es verion--5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I make it.

When I used

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/es-head/?auth_user=elastic&auth_password=changeme
```

I got the message

```
Cannot GET /es-pack/
```

So I change it to

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/?auth_user=elastic&auth_password=changeme
```

I want to know why?